Deploying MLflow Tracking on Azure Web App from Docker Image - Log Access
I'm trying to deploy an MLflow Tracking server on an Azure Web App using a Docker image. The setup works locally with Azure Blob Storage for artifacts and Azure SQL for the backend. I pushed the Docker image to Azure Container Registry and created a Web App using that image. I also set the necessary environment variables.
When i run the following to acces the log :
az webapp log tail --resource-group mlflow_deployment --name mlflowWebApp

I get :
Failed to connect to 'https://mlflowwebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/logstream' with status code '503' and reason 'Service Unavailable'

its been 2 weeks trying, ive tried : Restarting the web app / Checking Docker image and environment variables / Checking that Azure services (SQL, Blob Storage) are correctly configured.

What finally works for me is to rebuild the image using this command before pushing it (this issue is just related to Mac apparently)
Docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t mlflowserver:latest .

